# WiX DisableRegistryReflection="yes" attribute does not work

Tags: installation, wix, x86, 64-bit

I'm trying to disable registry reflection in WiX.
Because I want to write in `Key="Software\\[Manufacturer]\\[ProductName]"`, regardless of platform. When I install my app on x64 platform, installer replace key `"Software\Wow6432Node\\[Manufacturer]\\[ProductName]"`

When I set `DisableRegistryReflection="yes"` attribute, installer still write to `"Software\Wow6432Node\\[Manufacturer]\\[ProductName]"`.

```
<Component DisableRegistryReflection="yes" Id="SampleID">
  <RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="Software\[Manufacturer]\[Product Name]" Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall">
     <RegistryValue Type="string" Value="[UpdaterLocation]" Name="RootFolder"/>
  </RegistryKey>
</Component>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's imposible, becouse I have clearly 32 bit component.

Answer (score 4):

To write in that portion of the registry you must mark you component as 64-bit Win64="yes"

Comment: This is clearly not a 32 bit component if you want to write in the 64-bit part of the registry. However since the MSI doesn't support registry redirection, you will have to use a custom action to write the entry. Plase see this link on how to do this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa384129%28VS.85%29.aspx